# Lambda, Java and CloudEvents

Tags: java, json, aws-lambda, cloudevents

I a have a Lambda function (java), which get triggered from Confluent Cloud Lambda Connector.

The Lambda is being triggered but is failing because of deserialization errors.

The signature is as follows

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<CloudEvent, Map<String, String>> {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

public Map<String,String> handleRequest(CloudEvent event, Context context) {
```

The error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: >com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of io.cloudevents.CloudEvent (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at >com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:184)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of io.cloudevents.CloudEvent (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1592)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1228)
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:182)
```

Has anyone faced this before and knows how I should tackle it?

Comment: Please reformat your question as the formatting seems to be incorrect.

Comment: If you change the code from CloudEvent to String and log the input what does it look like?